# isomorphic automorphism groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

As I am sure some of you may have noticed I'm doing a series of exercises by Rotman and I am finding difficulties. Now I unbeaten into this problem

> Give an example of an abelian and a non-abelian group with isomorphic automorphism groups.

Can you help me?

Comment: Hint: this is surprisingly easy.

Comment: May be u can think of groups $G$ which has $|\text{Aut}(G)|=p$ for some prime $p$.Then u are through

Comment: @Chandru: that's not possible unless $p=2$, and even then, $G$ has to be abelian.

Comment: @Chandru: please stop leaving unhelpful comments. It is annoying to indicate that a comment is incorrect because it is not possible to downvote comments so I would _strongly recommend_ that you stop doing this or I may have to start deleting them.

Comment: Please don't yell.

Answer (score 3):

Try $A=\mathbb{F}_2^2$, and $G=S_3$.

Comment: This is correct...but there's something about the question that unsettles me.  I don't understand how the OP can be all out of ideas: to me, the obvious thing to try is **just compute the automorphism groups of some small groups** and see whether you get any coincidences.  You learn a lot by doing this: e.g. it is probably more useful to know the automorphism groups of your $A$ and $G$ above than it is to know the answer to this specific question.  If the OP didn't know to try this "technique", we should have told him/her (I think Jack Schmidt's comment was along these lines)....

Comment: If the OP knows that this is what s/he should do but can't actually carry it out, than s/he has a much more basic problem with the material that we are just papering over by giving an answer.  I am not scolding you by any means, but there are issues here to keep in mind: we should be teaching people how to fish rather than catching fish for them, if possible.

Comment: @Pete L.Clark . You're right, I'm taking the first steps in group theory, and so I asked for help not complete resolution exercise. In this type of exercises I can use brute force, in the sense that I am able to find all automorphisms of a group and then subsequent comparisons, the fact is that to find an example it took me a long time, then I'm asking whether there is indeed a theorem, or more, which allows me to limit the search to the types of groups